# Scala - Standalone UI available?

Tags: scala

I know that Scala has Swing (exclusively) as stand alone UI.
Is there any better UI (like JavaFX in Java) in Scala.For a better look and feel.
Please help.

Comment: [there is a wrapper for javafx](http://www.scalafx.org/)

Comment: Hi ..
Am getting Error like "not found: object scalafx". should we install something
am using intellij-community edition- but i got a javafx is running fine

Comment: Should I ask in as different question ?

Comment: yep, different question is a way to go normally, though scalafx does not provided out of the box, you need to somehow include it to your project (maven/sbt/gradle or just jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is no. Scala does not include a UI framework on its own. You can either use any java UI framework (swing, javaFX and others) via java interop (which is trivial) or find a scala wrapper for one of them (as the comment above).

I mainly post this since your question is else likely to go unanswered, which is kind of a burden on the site.